# Fetch Videos from Video App

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, uiimagepickercontroller, phassetcollection

Need some support in fetching videos which are available in default videos app. I tried with PHAssetCollection & UIImagePickerControler it din't work as excepted.

```
UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        mediaUI.delegate = self;
        [mediaUI setMediaTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]];
        [self presentViewController:mediaUI animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: There is no API to access videos from the Videos app.

Comment: @maddy I can see few apps in appstore. They are able to fetch videos from Video app. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/video-2-cameraroll-save-movie/id1014376422?mt=8